# Command to delete files in UNC path

Tags: batch-file, unc

Hi I tried below command to delete files in UNC path

```
set folder="\\SERVERNAME\Publish" 
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

But I got error saying:

```
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows Directory
```

Somehow I need to delete files that are residing in Server's shared path using batch command. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**edited** 2015-09-16 - Original answer remains at the bottom

Code reformated to avoid removal of non desired folders if the mapping fails. Only if the `pushd` suceeds the removal is executed.

```dos
set "folder=\\SERVERNAME\Publish" 
pushd "%folder%" && (
    for /d %%i in (*) do rmdir "%%i" /s /q 
    popd
)
```

---

**original answer:**

```dos
set "folder=\\SERVERNAME\Publish" 
pushd "%folder%"
for /d %%i in (*) do rmdir "%%i" /s /q 
popd
```

`pushd` will create a drive mapping over the unc path and then change to it. Then, all the operations are over drive:\folders. At the end `popd` will remove the drive assignation.

Comment: I had to replace single ' with double "

Comment: @aggaton, I don't know how I didn't remove the quotes (copy/paste from original code, I think). Thank you. Anyway, the quotes are not even needed.

Answer (score 1):

This deletes all files with name like 'ms' and over a year.

```
@echo off
set "year=-365"
PushD "\\SERVERNAME\FolderName" && (
  "forfiles.exe" /s /m "*_ms_*" /d %year% /c "cmd /c del @file"
) & PopD
```